# Changing my code to use async methods instead of sync methods will force my WebClient to never timeout (20 minute++)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, webclient

I have 2 asp.net MVC web applications , as follow:-

1. **ApplicationA** . which is an Asp.net mvc-4 deployed under iis-8.
2. **ApplicationB**. which is an Asp.net mvc-5 deployed under iis-8.

now inside my ApplicationA i have the following method,which will call an action method (home/sync) on applicationB , as follow:-

```
public List<Technology> GetTechnology(int? currentfiltertype)
  {
     try
      {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
         {
           string url = currentURL + "home/sync?filtertype=" + currentfiltertype;
           wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
           string json = wc.DownloadString(url);
           List<Technology> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Technology>>(json);
           return result;
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e){}
  }
```

now i have noted that when the `WebClient` calls the action method, and the method did not receive a response within around 2 minutes it will raise a timeout exception. But since the `home/sync` action method on web application B needs around 30 minutes to complete.. so i was searching for a solution to extend the web-client timeout period. so i tried changing my code to use async methods as follow,mainly by replacing `wc.DownloadString` with `wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync` as follow:-

```
public async Task<List<Technology>> GetTechnology(int? currentfiltertype)
{
   try
    {
      using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
       {
         string url = currentURL + "home/sync?filtertype=" + currentfiltertype;
         wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
         string json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
         List<Technology> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Technology>>(json);
         return result;
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

and now seems the `WebClient` will never expired ... i tried calling the action method and the web client keep waiting for a response for more than 20 minutes without raising any timeout exception, then it received the response from web applicationB and everything worked well..
so can anyone advice why changing my code to use async methods as shown in the above code, caused the `WebClient` to not timeout ?? i can not understand the relation between using async logic and extending the timeout period for the web-client (not sure if the WebClient will ever timeout inside async methods!!)?

Comment: Anything that takes 30 minutes should *not* be running in a web application. If you need to do some long-running task, you should offload it to a background process.

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes you are correct ,, i always define long-running processes inside seperate console applications, but for this one i need to run it under IIS ,, as it will only generates a report,, so if the application pool restart during the long-running operation , then there is no real damage to my data ,, in this case the user need to regenerate the report ..

Comment: why some one vote to CLOSE this question ,, any reason?

Comment: I don't see how "it will only generate a report" validates a "need to run it under IIS". A web server is designed to return quick responses. It is not intended and is flat-out not suited to handling a 20 minute request. You need to do it outside of your web process.

Comment: @ChrisPratt you are 100% correct ,,will consider this will chnage my code to run under a console app instead... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can anyone advice why changing my code to use async methods as shown in the above code, caused the WebClient to not timeout ??

The answer is a bit convoluted: [`WebClient` is based on `WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.getwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx), and [`HttpWebRequest`'s `Timeout` property is only honored for synchronous requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx).

> (noy sure if the WebClient will ever timeout inside async methods!!)?

It does not *directly* support asynchronous timeouts, but it does support [(its own kind of) cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx), which you can trigger after a timer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your helpful reply. so when i am using "await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);" this will never timeout is this correct ? second questino what are the drawback if i keep my async code as is ? so it will never timedout for the webclient calls ??

Comment: @johnG: It'll never time out on the client side; it's still possible to have the server time out and send an error response. If you keep your code as-is (without timeout), then you won't have a client timeout.

Comment: now when you say it will never timeout on the client ,, then you mean that the WebClient using async method will never timeout.. but it is not clear to me what you mean by it might timeout on the server ??? why would the server timeout ?

Comment: Most servers have a maximum time for a request, and will abort the request if it goes too long.

Comment: now i am hosting my web site inside iis-8 so where i can check when the server will timeout ? and do u know what is the default time out for the server ?

Comment: @johnG: No, I don't know, sorry.